# ibeacon powered on as opposed to enter or leaving region

Tags: ios, ibeacon

I have been playing around with various test apps that detect when the device enters or leaves the iBeacon's region but my question is are there any apps that will detect when a beacon is turned on?

The reason I ask is that if I sit in the same room as my iPhone and remove the battery from the beacon then re-insert it the none of the apps that I have tried so far trigger a region entered response.

Please excuse my non tech question as until I can find out if this type of detection is possible I haven't yet fully immersed myself in the coding as it may not be suitable for my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about it from your phone's perspective:  Powering down an iBeacon looks exactly the same as moving out of its transmitter range.  Likewise powering up an iBeacon looks exactly the same as entering its transmitter range.

The way that the iOS CoreLocation monitoring callbacks work (didEnterRegion / didExitRegion) is exactly the same for the two cases above.

I suspect the reason you aren't seeing a didEnterRegion callback when you power on your iBeacon is because you didn't leave it unpowered long enough.  It takes time for iOS CoreLocation to decide the phone exited a region, and it generally won't tell you that you entered a region if it thinks it never left it.

Two suggestions to make this easier for you.

1. When doing testing like this, always verify you get a didExitRegion indication before expecting a didEnterRegion event.  (Add NSLog lines to your appDelegate to help you see this.)
2. Turn on ranging for iBeacons whenever you set up monitoring for iBeacons.  This makes the time needed to detect region transitions much faster when you are in the foreground.

More information on the time it takes to detect region transitions can be found in [this blog post](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/11/13/ibeacon-monitoring-in-the-background-and-foreground.html).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me towards the Radius blog, I'd missed that. I can confirm that what you suspected was in fact the reason. 

I had been popping out the battery and replacing it like an eager infant. After removing the battery I waited until the outside the region message popped up (doh) and after reinserting the battery the inside region message popped up within seconds every time. 

I will now be a good chap and immerse myself in the code and won't come out until I have it working.

If it helps anyone else I was using the radius app and iBeacon Manager from J David Crow to test.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar experiences and assume the phone checks for new beacon only when you move around. That makes sense from an energy saving perspective and the main use case of beacons.

Comment: This is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

To detect a beacon when it's powered on is possible, if the **CLLocationManager** object is currently ranging for the beacon, and it's already in range.

The thing to understand here is the difference between region monitoring and beacon ranging.

Some apps only start with region monitoring, ranging only when a region is entered, and stop ranging when the region is exited.(taking the batteries out will cause the region to be exited) When you put the batteries back in, the beacon in this case is not detected because ranging has been stopped.

When your app launches start ranging with **startRangingBeaconsInRegion:** method and don't stop this anywhere in your code.